# Integral Prefactoring Anomaly

Tags: calculus, integration

This started out as a question but in the course of going through the work of generating the question, the answer to the question became apparent. Since I'm essentially a self taught calculus explorer, these types of discoveries hold a special meaning to me. So in that spirit I will post this to be archived as a reference for my ongoing mathematical development.

Any feedback or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Enjoy!

Evaluating the integral:

$$\int \left( \frac{x + 4}{2x + 6} \right)dx$$

My steps with pre-factoring the denominator:

$$\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int \left( \frac{x + 4}{2x + 6} \right)dx \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{x + 4}{2(x + 3)} \right)dx \\[1em]
   u &= x + 3 \\[1em]
(x + 3)dx &= du\\[1em]
\left( \frac{d}{dx}(x + 3) \right)dx &= du \\[1em]
\left( \frac{d}{dx}(x) + \frac{d}{dx}(3) \right)dx &= du \\[1em]
\left( \frac{d}{dx}(x) + 0\right)dx &= du \\[1em]
\left( \frac{dx}{dx} + 0 \right)dx &= du \\[1em]
(1 + 0)dx &= du \\[1em]
(1)dx &= du \\[1em]
  dx &= \left( \frac{1}{1} \right)du \\[1em]
  dx &= du \\[1em]
F(\ ) &= \int \frac{x + 4}{2u}du \\[1em]
F(\ ) &= \int \left( \frac{x}{2u} + \frac{4}{2u} \right)du \\[1em]
   u &= x + 3 \\[1em]
x + 3 &= u \\[1em]
   x &= u - 3\\[1em]
F(u) &= \int \left( \frac{u - 3}{2u} + \frac{2}{u} \right) du \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{u}{2u} - \frac{3}{2u} + \frac{2}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{2u} + \frac{2}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)du - \int \left( \frac{3}{2u} \right)du + \int \left( \frac{2}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)du - \int \left( \frac{3}{2u} \right)du + 2* \int\left( \frac{1}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)du - \int \left( \frac{3}{2u} \right)du + 2*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)du - \frac{3}{2}*\int \left( \frac{1}{u} \right)du + 2*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)du - \frac{3}{2}*\ln|u| + 2*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \int \left( \frac{1}{2}*u^0 \right)du - \frac{3}{2}*\ln|u| + 2*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\int \left(u^0 \right)du - \frac{3}{2}*\ln|u| + 2*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\frac {1}{(0 + 1)}*u^{(0 + 1)} - \frac{3}{2}*\ln|u| + 2*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{1}*u^1 - \frac{3}{2}*\ln|u| + 2*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \frac{u}{2} - \frac{3}{2}*\ln|u| + 2*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \frac{u}{2} - \frac{3}{2}*\ln|u| + \frac{4}{2}*\ln|u| \\[1em]
     &= \frac{u}{2} + \frac{\ln|u|}{2} \\[1em]
   u &= x + 3 \\[1em]
F(x) &= \frac{(x + 3)}{2} + \frac{\ln|x + 3|}{2} \\[1em]
     &= \frac{x}{2} + \frac{3}{2} + \frac{\ln|x + 3|}{2} \\[1em]
     &= \frac{x}{2} + \frac{\ln|x + 3|}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \\[1em]
     &= \frac{(x + \ln|x + 3| + 3)}{2} \\[1em]
F(x) &= \bf \left[\frac{(x + \ln|x + 3| + 3)}{2} + C \right]
\end{align}$$

My steps without pre-factoring the denominator:

$$\begin{align}
G(x) &= \int \left( \frac{x + 4}{2x + 6} \right)dx \\[1em]
   u &= 2x + 6 \\[1em]
(2x + 3)dx &= du\\[1em]
\left( \frac{d}{dx}(2x + 6) \right)dx &= du \\[1em]
\left( \frac{d}{dx}(2x) + \frac{d}{dx}(6) \right)dx &= du \\[1em]
\left( \frac{d}{dx}(2x) + 0\right)dx &= du \\[1em]
\left( 2*\frac{d}{dx}(x) + 0\right)dx &= du \\[1em]
\left( 2*\frac{dx}{dx} + 0 \right)dx &= du \\[1em]
(2 + 0)dx &= du \\[1em]
(2)dx &= du \\[1em]
   dx &= \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)du \\[1em]
G(\ ) &= \int \left( \frac{x + 4}{u}*\frac{1}{2} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\int \left( \frac{x + 4}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\int \left( \frac{x}{u} + \frac{4}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
   u &= 2x + 6 \\[1em]
2x + 6 &= u \\[1em]
  2x &= u - 6 \\[1em]
   x &= \frac{u}{2} - \frac{6}{2} \\[1em]
   x &= \frac{u}{2} - 3 \\[1em]
G(u) &= \frac{1}{2}*\int \left( \left(\frac{u}{2} - 3 \right)* \frac{1}{u} + \frac{4}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\int \left( \frac{u}{2}*\frac{1}{u} - 3*\frac{1}{u}  + \frac{4}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\int \left( \frac{u}{2u} - \frac{3}{u} + \frac{4}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}* \int \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{3}{u} + \frac{4}{u} \right)du \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\int\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)du - \int\left(\frac{3}{u}\right)du + \int\left(\frac{4}{u}\right)du\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\int\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)du - \int\left(\frac{3}{u}\right)du + 4*\int\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)du\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\int\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)du - \int\left(\frac{3}{u}\right)du + 4*\ln|u|\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\int\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)du - 3*\int\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)du + 4*\ln|u|\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\int\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)du - 3*\ln|u| + 4*\ln|u|\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\int\left(\frac{1}{2}*u^0\right)du - 3*\ln|u| + 4*\ln|u|\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\frac{1}{2}*\int\left(u^0\right)du - 3*\ln|u| + 4*\ln|u|\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{(0 + 1)}*u^{(0 + 1)} - 3*\ln|u| + 4*\ln|u| \right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{1}*u^1 - 3*\ln|u| + 4*\ln|u|\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\frac{u}{2} - 3*\ln|u| + 4*\ln|u|\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\frac{u}{2} + \ln|u|\right) \\[1em]
     &= \frac{u}{4} + \frac{\ln|u|}{2} \\[1em]
   u &= 2x + 6 \\[1em]
G(x) &= \frac{(2x + 6)}{4} + \frac{\ln|2x + 6|}{2} \\[1em]
     &= \frac{2x}{4} + \frac{6}{4} + \frac{\ln|2x + 6|}{2} \\[1em]
     &= \frac{x}{2} + \frac{3}{2} + \frac{\ln|2x + 6|}{2} \\[1em]
     &= \frac{x + 3 + \ln|2x + 6|}{2} \\[1em]
     &= \frac{x + \ln|2x + 6| + 3}{2} \\[1em]
G(x) &= \bf \left[\frac{x + \ln|2x + 6| + 3}{2} + C \right] \\[1em]
\end{align}$$

Clearly $F(x) ≠ G(x)$. $$\begin{align}
F(x) - G(x) &= \left(\frac{x + \ln|x + 3| + 3}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{x + \ln|2x + 6| + 3}{2}\right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{x + \ln|x + 3| + 3}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{\ln|2x + 6|}{2} + \frac{3}{2}\right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{\ln|x + 3|}{2} + \frac{3}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{\ln|2x + 6|}{2} + \frac{3}{2}\right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{\ln|x + 3|}{2} + \frac{3}{2}\right) - \frac{x}{2} - \frac{\ln|2x + 6|}{2} - \frac{3}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{\ln|x + 3|}{2} - \frac{\ln|2x + 6|}{2} - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln|x + 3|}{2} - \frac{\ln|2x + 6|}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln|x + 3| - \ln|2x + 6|}{2} \\[1em]
F(x) - G(x) &= \bf\left[\frac{\ln\left|\frac{x\:+\:3}{2x\:+\:6}\right|}{2}\right] \\[1em]
\end{align}$$

As a sanity check, I inputted the integral into wolfram and symbolab:

When I enter the integration into Wolfram, I get my [F(x)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%28x%20%2B%204%29%2F%282x%20%2B%206%29dx) result.

And for Symbolab, it returns the close to my [G(x)](http://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20%5Cleft(%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%20%2B%204%7D%7B2x%20%2B%206%7D%20%5Cright)dx/?origin=button) result.

$$\int\left(\frac{x+4}{2x+6}\right)dx = \frac{\frac{2x+6}{2}+\ln\left(2x+6\right)}{2}+C $$After a little cleanup:

$$\begin{align}
\int\left(\frac{x + 4}{2x + 6}\right)dx &= \frac{\frac{2x + 6}{2} + \ln\left(2x + 6\right)}{2} + C \\[1em]
&= \frac{\frac{2(x + 3)}{2} + \ln\left(2x + 6\right)}{2} + C \\[1em]
&= \frac{x + 3 + \ln\left(2x + 6\right)}{2} + C \\[1em]
&= \bf\left[\frac{x + \ln\left(2x + 6\right) + 3}{2} + C \right] \\[1em]
\end{align}$$At this point I was certain that evaluating F(x) and G(x) as definite integrals would give me different answers.

So I tried evaluating both results as definite integrals:

I picked -2 and 2 because the original function:

$$f(x) = \frac{x + 4}{2x + 6}$$

evaluates to tidy values of 1 and 0.6 respectively.

$$F(x) = \frac{x + \ln|x + 3| + 3}{2}$$
$$\begin{align}
  F(2) - F(-2) &= \left(\frac{2 + \ln|2 + 3| + 3}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{-2 + \ln|-2 + 3| + 3}{2}\right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{2 + \ln(5) + 3}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{-2 + \ln(1) + 3}{2}\right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{2 + \ln(5) + 3}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{-2 + 0 + 3}{2}\right)  \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{2 + \ln(5) + 3}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln(5) + 5}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln(5)}{2} + \frac{5}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln(5)}{2} + \frac{4}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \bf\left[\frac{\ln(5)}{2} + 2\right] \\[1em]
\end{align}$$And now for G(x):

$$G(x) = \frac{x + \ln|2x + 6| + 3}{2} $$
$$\begin{align}
  G(2) - G(-2) &= \left(\frac{2 + \ln|2*2 + 6| + 3}{2} \right) - \left(\frac{-2 + \ln|2*-2 + 6| + 3}{2} \right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{2 + \ln|4 + 6| + 3}{2} \right) - \left(\frac{-2 + \ln|-4 + 6| + 3}{2} \right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{2 + \ln(10) + 3}{2} \right) - \left(\frac{-2 + \ln(2) + 3}{2} \right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{\ln(10) + 5}{2} \right) - \left(\frac{\ln(2) + 1}{2} \right) \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{\ln(10)}{2} + \frac{5}{2} \right) - \left(\frac{\ln(2)}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln(10)}{2} + \frac{5}{2} - \frac{\ln(2)}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln(10)}{2} - \frac{\ln(2)}{2} + \frac{5}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln(10)}{2} - \frac{\ln(2)}{2} + \frac{4}{2} \\[1em]
 &= \frac{\ln(10)}{2} - \frac{\ln(2)}{2} + 2 \\[1em]
 &= \left(\frac{\ln(10)}{2} - \frac{\ln(2)}{2}\right) + 2 \\[1em]
 &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\ln(10) - \ln(2)\right) + 2 \\[1em]
 &= \frac{1}{2}*\left(\ln\left(\frac{10}{2}\right)\right) + 2 \\[1em]
 &= \frac{1}{2}*\ln(5) + 2 \\[1em]
 &= \bf\left[\frac{\ln(5)}{2} + 2\right] \\[1em]
\end{align}$$

I was not expecting that result at all. After checking and re-checking my math and coming up with the same results I decided to try and graph everything to see if I could understand why two different indefinite integrals could evaluate to the same value as definite integrals.

$$\begin{align}
\bf\color{Red}f\color{Red}(\color{Red}x\color{Red}) &= \frac{x + 4}{2x + 6}  \\[1em]
\bf\color{Blue}F\color{Blue}(\color{Blue}x\color{Blue}) &= \frac{(x + \ln|x + 3| + 3)}{2} \\[1em]
\bf\color{Green}G\color{Green}(\color{Green}x\color{Green}) &= \frac{x + \ln|2x + 6| + 3}{2} \\[1em]
\end{align}$$

[image]

After staring at the graph, it dawned on me that the two integrals have the exact same slope at any given $x$, which means that for any interval of $x$ values, the delta will always be the same.

In effect, the difference:

$$\frac{\ln\left|\frac{x\:+\:3}{2x\:+\:6}\right|}{2}$$

is essentially a constant that will be nulled when completing the $F(b)-F(a)$ or $G(b)-G(a)$ subtraction. Which ultimately means you can have an infinite number of definite solutions so long as the slopes at any given $x$ are equal. And when they are evaluated as definite integrals the outcomes will always be the same: $y$ offsets will have no effect on definite integral calculations.

Comment: EPIC post... But I couldn't make it past your fifth equals sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two algebraically equivalent expressions are going to have the same antiderivative, you just have to be careful in the details of the calculations:
\begin{align}
\int {x+4\over 2x+6}\,dx&={1\over 2}\int {x+4\over x+3}\,dx\\
&=\color{blue}{{1\over 2}\int {u+1\over u}\,du} \qquad \text{using }u=x+3,\ du=dx;\ u+1=x+4\\
&={1\over 2}\int (1+u^{-1})\,du\\
&={1\over 2}\left(u+\ln|u|\right)+C\\
&=\color{red}{{1\over 2}\left(x+3+\ln|x+3|\right)+C}\tag{1}
\end{align}
while on the other hand
\begin{align}
\int {x+4\over 2x+6}\,dx
&=\int {u\over 2u-2}\,du \ \ \text{using }u=x+4,\ du=dx;\ \therefore 2u=2x+8,\ 2u-2=2x+6\\
&={1\over 2}\int {u\over u-1}\,du\\
&=\color{blue}{{1\over 2}\int {v+1\over v}\,dv} \quad\text{using }v=u-1,\ dv=du;\ \therefore u=v+1\\
\end{align}
and this last integral is the same as the integral we arrived at by the previous method Their values are the same once you finish out the calculations and substitute all the way back to the $x$ variable:
$$\color{blue}{{1\over 2}\int {v+1\over v}\,dv}=\color{red}{{1\over 2}\left(x+3+\ln|x+3|\right)+C}.\tag{2}$$

---

I think the issue is your confusion/surprise at the fact that $F(x)-G(x)\not=0$. But that difference doesn't have to be *zero*, it only has to be (and will be) *a constant*. [This is a result that you should have (or add) in your calculus repertoire:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration#Reason_for_a_constant_difference_between_antiderivatives)

> Any two antiderivatives of a given function $f(x)$ differ by a
>   constant.

And your calculations bear this out. Notice
$$F(x)-G(x)=\ln\left|{{x+3\over 2x+6}\over 2}\right|=\ln\left|{{x+3\over 2(x+3)}\over 2}\right|=\ln\left|{{1\over 2}\over 2}\right|=\ln|1/4|,$$
which is indeed *constant*!

This is really no different than having chosen the constant of integration to be $C_1$ in $(1)$ and $C_2$ in $(2)$, where $C_1-C_2=\ln|1/4|$.

---

Having said all of that, the main point from the integration work I showed above is that if you are consistent in your changes of variables, you will end up with the same antiderivative in both cases, ${1\over 2}\left(x+3+\ln|x+3|\right)$,
with the only difference being "up to an additive constant".

Comment: Didn't think to try a double u-v substitution. Especially since the two premier online equation resolvers were validating both of my approaches above.